# Как добавить линию за текст в css?

Tags: css, вёрстка

Как реализовать горизонтальную линию за текстом как на картинке?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал использовать свойство box-shadow - линия появляется ниже текста на несколько пикселей. Line-height не помогает т.к. меняется междустрочный интервал, а не отступ тени. Есть какое-нибудь свойство, которое указывает отступ box-shadow?
Псевдоэлемент :after применяется ко всему тексту как к блоку, а не к строкам как на фото.

Как реализовать подобную линию?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: можно использовать `<hr>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  max-width: 400px;
}

h1 span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

h1 span::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20%; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 20%;
  background-color: orange;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>Наши партнеры</span>
  <span>по бизнесу</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. вот так ?

```css
p{
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
}
p:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 290px;
  max-width: 290px;
  height: 5px;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: orange;
}
p:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 190px;
  max-width: 190px;
  height: 5px;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<p>наши партнеры <br>по бизнесу</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Практически идентичный вопрос уже был: [Как реализовать такое подчеркивание в CSS?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1150492/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-css/1150540#1150540)

Я там в ответе предложил использовать фоновый градиент.